# java regex pattern to format number with space "xxxx xxx xxx"

Tags: java, regex

There's below number

```
0135782145
```

I need use java regex to format above string into below pattern

```
0135 782 145
```

Help me to provide simple regex pattern for java to convert this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "0135782145";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\d{4})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})", "$1 $2 $3");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
0135 782 145
```

Comment: Might want to add `^` and `$`, so it leaves input with wrong length unchanged. In which case `replaceFirst` might be a more appropriate call, though `replaceAll` works too.

Comment: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) strongly recommends only answering well-asked questions. In this case, there is no attempt being shown in the question, nor there is any specific issues or roadblocks stated.